# Approximate distribution for sum of squares of standardized Poisson random variables

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, asymptotics

Suppose that $X_1, ..., X_n$ are independent and identically distributed Poisson($\lambda$) random variables.

What is a good approximating distribution for $\sum_{i = 1}^{200} \frac{(X_i - \lambda)^2}{\lambda}$?

I think that it is $\chi^2_{200}$, because it is a sum of the squares of standardized normal random variables.   However, I'm not sure if they really are standardized normal random variables.

Comment: They (the $(X_i-\lambda)/\sqrt{\lambda}$) are not standardized normal random variables: they are standardized *Poisson* variables!  There are many possible answers.  Which are good ones depend on what you mean by a "good" approximation: could you tell us what aspects of the approximation need to be good and how you measure how good they are?

Comment: I don't have any criteria for "good". I'm eager to learn all the possibilities.

Comment: There are innumerable possibilities.  Perhaps you could tell us the context in which this question arises or the actual statistical problem you are dealing with?

Comment: Two possibilities out of "innumerably many": If $\lambda$ is large then $X_i$ are nearly normal, $Z_i =(X_i - \lambda)/\sqrt{\lambda}$ are nearly standard normal, and the sum of 200 $Z_i^2$ is nearly CHISQ(200), which in turn is nearly normal. (Why and with what $\mu$ and $\sigma$ ?). // If $\lambda$ is very small, then the $X_i$ are mostly zeros and ones, and normal by CLT seems a better fit to the sum of 200.

Comment: This question is from an exam in a second-year course in mathematical statistics.  There is no more context.  The question actually asks for the expected value of the approximate distribution.

Comment: I suspect that the instructor is asking us to apply the central limit theorem.

Comment: Please don't assume that $\lambda$ is big.

Comment: In most cases it is easier to compute expectations than it is to obtain the entire distribution, and one can often compute the expectation exactly without recourse to approximation.  That is the case here. Thus, if your interest really is in answering the exam question, then please ask the exam question and explain the steps you have already taken towards answering it.

Comment: The exam question asks for the approximating distribution - just as I posed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible approximations. But I guess the idea here is simply CLT.

Consider that, for large $n$, the sum $Z= \sum_n Y_i$ tends to a normal $N(n\mu ,n \sigma^2 )$
if $Y_i$ are iid variables of mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

In our case $Y_i = \frac{(X_i-\lambda)^2}{\lambda}$, with $X_i$ being a $\lambda-$Poisson.

We only need to calculate the expectation and variance of $Y_i$, I leave that to you.

Notice that the approximation is obviously wrong in some respects: in particular, $Z$ is non-negative and discrete.

> I'm not sure if [it's the sum of the squares of] standardized normal random variables.

No, of course not. $\frac{(X_i-\lambda)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ is a "standardized" Poisson variable. Hence it not justified to assume that $Z$ is $\chi^2_{200}$.

Comment: Ah - that makes sense. Thanks for providing a clear, concise, and straightforward answer to my question. I knew that it would not be so complicated!